# BATCH /f invalid switch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have problem with this little script complier return error "invalid switch -f". This throws me for a loop :-| Could you help me? Many thanks.

```
@echo off

set maxbytesize=2000000000 
set /a c=1
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %D:\Temp\IKS\MAO\*.MP4%') do ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i %%i -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts %%~ni.ts
FOR /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %D:\Temp\IKS\MAO\*.ts%') do ( 

if %%~zi GTR %maxbytesize% (
    echo file '%%i' >> ts_list.txt
) else ( 
    echo file '%%i' >> ts_list.txt
    set /a c=c+1
    ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i ts_list.txt -c copy output_!c!.mp4
    del /f ts_list.txt
    del /f *.ts
)

)

endlocal
```

Comment: The message you quoted looks more like ffmpeg complaining than cmd. On a side note, I would move the `SETLOCAL` command above the variable assignments, unless you want those variables to be set in the shell that invoked the script.

Comment: please look at the ffmpeg man page `"invalid switch -f"`

Comment: The only two lines that use -f both have it being passed to  `ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe`, so the problem is not the batch file. It's the call to `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Ohm, i'm quite surprise that i didnt notice the problem with setlocal :/ now its ok...i'm going to open the manual...

Comment: ffmpeg has felt 10000 switches ..... for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you replace the `%`

```
FOR /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d    HERE>> %D:\Temp\IKS\MAO\*.MP4%  << HERE
FOR /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d    HERE>> %D:\Temp\IKS\MAO\*.ts% << AND HERE
```

with `"` in each case.

Might just work a little better that way...

Comment: Okay, i've just replaced it...now compiler returns "System canot find specified path"...but i'm pretty sure that the path si right.

Comment: Perhaps `ffmpeg` needs to have `%%~fi` instead of `%%i` and `%%~dpni` in place of `%%~ni` so that it's looking in the DATA dource directory, not whatever default it uses. May be an idea to enclose those in rabbit's ears to permit spaces - commonly used in `.mp4`s. Either way, the `-f` problem appears solved...

Comment: I´m wondering and i think it could be problem with paths...Is it correct way, how i specified them?
FOR /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d "D:\Temp\*.MP4"')...Could you see any syntax mistake?

Comment: `"D:\Temp*.MP4"` is perfectly valid syntax - BUT what it would mean is "files named `Tempsomething.mp4` in directory `D:\`. From your earlier comments, it would seem that you may want "files named `something.mp4` in any directory below `temp`" - which is NOT the scenario you originally proposed. That syntax would be 'dir /s /b /a-d D:\temp\*.mp4`. If any file has spaces (etc) in its name, you'd need to add `"delims="` after the `/f` and since `%%i` would then contain the entire filename, you's access the target file with `"%%~i"` - including the quotes. Tip: `ECHO %%i` will show you the name.